# Connection to url block web connection

Tags: python

I connect to url, and it do something during ~5 minutes, At the same time it's impossible to connect to this site, because http request communicate with the same address

I run the python code by the ajax - in java script.

java script code:
var structure = {
    $: jQuery.noConflict(),

```
ExecuteUpdateData: function () {
    var $ = this.$,
        me = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ExecuteUpdateData/',
    }).done(function (result) {
        if (result != "Succeeded")
            alert('Failed to update data, the error message: ' + result)
        $("#update_data").attr("class", "update_data_on");
    });
}
```

}
Python code:
def UpdateData(a):
    print 'update data'

```
res = False
global_server = 'http://10.184.197.149:8055' 

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(global_server)
    url_res = response.read()
except Exception, e:
    print(e)
    return HttpResponse(e.message)

return HttpResponse(url_res.strip())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by "Task" in C# code that the url opened